# post a feed on my facebook application fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I know how to post something on my wall `$facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $feed);`
but how to post feed on my facebook application page and **this feed must be posted by the app**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// we need to get an application access_token first
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
   "client_id=" . $app_id .
   "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
   "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

// seperate the string returned to use it in the post array
$arr = explode("=",$app_token);
$app_token = $arr[1];

$post_id = $facebook->api("/$app_id/feed", "POST", array("access_token"=>$app_token,"message"=>"hello app!"));
```

Comment: thank this work perfectly, the concept of graph api and access_token still abstract for me .

Comment: thanks for that @ifaour.  Don't mean to bug you but you may be able to provide the expert view on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232224/facebook-post-to-wall-using-me-photos-in-2-1-facebook