# Facebook post to wall

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have a Facebook Application Profile Page that I would like to create a custom script to perform wall posts on its wall. The reason I need this is because the existing Facebook "Post to Wall" functionality does not post the pictures I want it to.

What I need is a PHP webpage that allows me to do this:

Inputs:

- App ID (App ID of the Facebook App that I am looking to post to wall)
- API Key
- App Secret
- URL of Image to post
- Message Body
- URL of link

Output:

- the post is made to the wall of the Facebook App Profile page, so that anyone who has "liked" the page can see it.

Any ideas, brainiacs?

Comment: What kind of images are you trying to post ?

Comment: I dont get what cant be done via their standard API?  Your not looking to do anything special that 1000's of other developers are doing via the API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [post a feed on my facebook application fan page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919788/post-a-feed-on-my-facebook-application-fan-page)

Answer (score 0):

That's all supported by the graph api, you'd need to submit to http://graph.facebook.com/app/feed with the post submitted as POST data (message), and of course an access token.  If you use Facebook's own php library, there are functions which will implement the api calls using the curl library for you.

If you haven't used the graph api before, you should start reading their developer resources at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api