# Facebook, post to wall, using me/photos, in 2.1 Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

Considering a Unity project from ~3 years ago, and using Facebook graph I'm pretty sure it was **1.0**,

You could post to a user's wall like this:

```
private byte[] imageAsBytes;
Texture2D im = ... your image
imageAsBytes = im.EncodeToPNG();
Dictionary<string, object> dct = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
    { "message", "Marketing message here" },
    { "picture", imageAsBytes }
    };
Facebook.instance.graphRequest(
       "me/photos", HTTPVerb.POST, dct, completionHandler );
```

As has been made known for many months now, there is a change to this coming.

With Facebook **2.1 being required as of this Aug 8,** I'm rather confused about, simply, whether this still works in 2.1?

in short, how to post an image to the user's wall, in 2.1?

Note - here's where to find the important resource CBRoe mentions below...

[image]

---

*Note that the only problem with the alternative, FB.FeedShare() is that, as far as I understand, you can not actually post an image (sure, you can link to an image at a URL).*

Comment: I believe that this call was deprecated because after 2.1 Facebook changed the terms of service and is enforcing the permissions and API calls ... However, if you just want to share in user's wall I suggest you using FB.FeedShare() ->  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.FeedShare  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Cabrra  - thanks - do you mean that, although "me/photos" is still there in the API "technically", in fact, they just do not allow it?

Comment: This isn’t deprecated in any way. But since API v2.0 you need to get the necessary permission reviewed and approved by Facebook, before you can ask normal users for it.

Comment: @CBroe that is key info, thanks.  I mean **key**, it's remarkable how difficult it is to get real facts on FB.  Maybe you should drop that in as an answer to help googlers coming this way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This isn’t deprecated in any way. But since API v2.0 you need to get the necessary permission reviewed and approved by Facebook, before you can ask normal users for it.**

---

And yes, this is a rather major change - but that's why it was announced way ahead of time, via a lot of channels. We all know how fast the IT world moves and changes- so I think you can not put the blame on Facebook here. If you were "out of the game" (this particular one) for over three years, you just have to go and find the resources that a) list what's changed, and b) what the current state of things is. And the developer section does both. The changelog has already been mentioned, and for example the need to get permissions reviewed now is also mentioned on [the starting page for Facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login), right at the top under *Essential Guides*.

Plus, Facebook actively informs you about changes - if you let them. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/contact/ where you'll find several options to get informed about specific stuff via e-mail.

Comment: Not top right, but right at the top - second headlined section here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Comment: thanks again @cbroe, i clicked over a bounty.  note that even with a huge bounty, there's like 1 person who knows this stuff!  :O

Answer (score 1):

You can check the changelog to see what changes happened https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog. There are no changes for `/me/photos` as far as I can tell.

It is possible to use image data or a URL.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos#Creating for more info

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... Hmm, on your second comment, for sure with me/photos, you can send an image.  However I believe with FB.FeedShare(), you can *only* send a URL - indeed, do you know if that is correct?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Joe I am not familiar with `FB.FeedShare()` it seems to be prompting the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) which is different from `/me/photos`